# SQL query, who visited in the past year

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am having problems with SQL querys. Specialy with this one, it goes like this.

I have 2 tables, patients and visits.

```
CREATE TABLE patients (
   ID_patients INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE visit(
    ID_visit INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DATE_visit DATE NOT NULL,
    FK_patients INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Now I would like to make a query, that would tell me which patients visited in the past year? And I don't mean in 2015 for instance but as in BETWEN(today-365 days) AND ( today -  730 days). I hope someone can give me some usefull tips.

Comment: Which column defines the relation between `patients` and `visit` table?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, there should be a third colum by
 FK_patients INTEGER NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from visit
where DATE_visit between
CURRENT_DATE - interval 2 year and CURRENT_DATE - interval 1 year;
```

Comment: This works fine, but you need to add  interval '2' and internval '1' , otherwise it wont work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: But: `select CURRENT_DATE - interval 2 year` return `2014-04-18`... it should works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fetch all the `patients` names:

```
SELECT patients.name 
  FROM patients, visit
 WHERE patients.id = visit.fk_patients
   AND DATE_visit BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - interval '2' year AND CURRENT_DATE - interval '1' year;
```